# UPDATE vs COUNT vs SELECT performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, sql-update

Is this statement true or false

The performance of these queries

```
SELECT * FROM table;

UPDATE table SET field = 1;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

Are identical

Or is there ever a case in which the performance of one will greatly differ from the other?

## UPDATE

1. I'm more interested if there's a large difference between the SELECT and the UPDATE. You can ignore the COUNT(*) if you want
2. Assume the select performs full table scan. The update will also perform update on all rows in the table.
3. Assume the update is only updating one field - though it will update all rows (it's an indexed field)
4. I know that they'll take different time and that they do different things. What I want to know is if the difference will be significant or not. EG. If the update will take 5 times longer than the select then it's significant. Use this as the threshold. And there's no need to be precise. Just give an approximation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are different resource types involved:

- disk I/O (this is the most costly part of every DBMS)
- buffer pressure: fetching a row will cause fetching a page from disk, which will need buffer memory to be stored in
- work/scratch memory for intermediate tables, structures and aggregates.
- "terminal" I/O to the front-end process.
- cost of locking, serialisation and versioning and journaling
- CPU cost : this is neglectable in most cases (compared to disk I/O)

The `UPDATE` query in the question is the hardest: it will cause *all* disk pages for the table to be fetched, put into buffers, altered into *new* buffers and written back to disk. In normal circumstances, it will also cause other processes to be locked out, with contention and even more buffer pressure as a result.

The `SELECT *` query needs all the pages, too; and it needs to convert/format them *all* into frontend-format and send them back to the frontend.

The `SELECT COUNT(*)` is the cheapest, on all resources. In the worst case *all* the disk pages have to be fetched. If an index is present, fewer disk- I/O and buffers are needed. The CPU cost is still neglectable (IMHO) and the "terminal" output is marginal.

Comment: do you think UPDATE will ever be 5 times greater than the SELECT *?

Comment: It depends. Every resource involved is a dimension in the final _formula_. And every dimension needs a weight factor to come to a `x = c * y` kind of formula. IOW: YMMV. There is also a certain impact on other non-related queries and processes (mostly WRT buffers,memory, and locks)

Comment: what if I do LIMIT on the update. Will that significantly reduce time taken? Eg suppose that without limit it'll update all 500000 rows in the table. Will making it LIMIT 1 (hence only update 1 row in the table) reduce the time taken to execute the query?

Comment: There is no LIMIT on an update possible. There is no order, since there is no `ORDER BY` clause on update. The only way to restrict an UPDATE statement is by means of a WHERE clause: `UPDATE personel SET salary = salary * 1.5 WHERE gender = 'f';`

Comment: not true, i just tried it it worked UPDATE guinea_pig SET something = 3 LIMIT 1;   and only the first row got updated

Comment: What is "the first row", does that depend on the phase of the moon? Maybe mysql is nondeterministic? (Hammer, screw)

Comment: no that's the first row that appears when you do a select instead of update...eg: SELECT * guinea_pig SET something = 3 LIMIT 1; Do you know the answer or not?

Answer (score 7):

When you say "performance", do you mean "how long it takes them to execute"?

- One of them is returning all data in all rows.
- One of them (if you remove the "FROM") is writing data to the rows.
- One is counting rows and returning none of the data in the rows.

All three of those queries are doing entirely different things.  Therefore, it is reasonable to conclude that all three of them will take different amounts of time to complete.

Most importantly, **why are you asking this question**?  What are you trying to solve?  I have a bad feeling that you're going down a wrong path by asking this.

Answer (score 2):

I have a large (granted indexed) table here at work, and this is what I found

select * from X (limited to the first 100,000 records) (12.5 seconds)

select count(*) from X (returned millions of records) (15.57 seconds)

Update on an indexed table is very fast (less then a second)

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT and UPDATE should be about the same (but they could easily vary, this depends on the database). COUNT(*) is cached in many databases, at some level, so that query could easily be O(1). Of course a lazy implementation of UPDATE could also be O(1), but I don't know of anyone doing that currently.

tl;dr: "False" or "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

All three queries do vastly different things.

They each have their own performance characteristics and are not directly comparable.

Can you clarify what you are attempting to investigate?